# Image not showing iPhone (Ok on all devices including Android)

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I looked through multiple posts on this but it doesn't seem applicable to my case. I've 2 background images that are not displaying on iPhone (only), it works fine for desktop and android

I have added this to index.html

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
```

In CSS they are both slightly coded differently, **image1**

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 15%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

And **image2**

```
.testimonials {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(img/testimonials.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  color: #fff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

In terms of responsive sizing, I'll only adjusted for jumbotron's other elements (eg h1, button) but nothing specific for testimonials

Can anyone shed some light please? Thank you!

Comment: It would be great to see a snippet/fiddle/codepen whatever displaying the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because iOS does not support **`background-attachment: fixed;`** fully. I will suggest to use **`background-attachment: scroll;`** for mobile devices using media query.

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .jumbotron,
  .testimonials {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

> ***[You can check here for support](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment)***